# Looping animation in jQuery based on input number

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I'm fairly new to jQuery. I want to have a looping animation where the user will type a number in a textbox. Hitting the submit button will make the div that wraps the textbox and the button to cycle to Point A, Point B, and back to starting point.

It seems that when I do, it only moves once to Point A - and never again, regardless of the input number. console.log() says that after the animation fires, the CSS properties remain as if it never animated at all. Here is the HTML code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="pp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="submit_container">
        <input type="text" id="submit_value">
        <button type="submit" id="submit_trigger">Submit</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit_trigger').click(function(){
    var submitValue = $('#submit_value').val();
    console.log(submitValue);
    for(; submitValue>0; submitValue--){
        if ($('#submit_container').css('margin-left')=="0px"){
            $('div').animate({'margin-left':'300px'});
        }
        if ($('#submit_container').css('margin-left')=="300px"){
            $('div').animate({'margin-left':'600px'});
        }
        if ($('#submit_container').css('margin-left')=="600px"){
            $('div').animate({'margin-left':'0px'});
        };
    };
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_trigger').click(function() {
    var submitValue = $('#submit_value').val();
    console.log(submitValue);
    for (; submitValue > 0; submitValue--) {
      if ($('#submit_container').css('margin-left') == "0px") {
        $('div').animate({
          'margin-left': '300px'
        });
      }
      if ($('#submit_container').css('margin-left') == "300px") {
        $('div').animate({
          'margin-left': '600px'
        });
      }
      if ($('#submit_container').css('margin-left') == "600px") {
        $('div').animate({
          'margin-left': '0px'
        });
      };
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="submit_container">
  <input type="text" id="submit_value">
  <button type="submit" id="submit_trigger">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the relation between `submitValue` and animation?

Comment: Added a plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/9tj5drY766iQwLvnqC95?p=catalogue

Comment: @SushilKumar - I already created a snippet - it also shows the issue

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan - Its the input number - times the div will cycle through point A, B, and back to starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animate function has a callback property that is triggered after the animation is complete. You need to use this callback function. In your implementation the for loop is ready before the first animation is complete. So use the callback to do the animation loop

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit_trigger').click(function () {
        var submitValue = $('#submit_value').val();
        console.log(submitValue);

        animateContainer(submitValue);


    });
    var animateContainer = function (submitValue) {
        submitValue -= 1;
        if (submitValue <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        if ($('#submit_container').css('margin-left') == "0px") {
            $('div').animate(
                { 'margin-left': '300px' },
                function () {
                    animateContainer(submitValue)
                });
        }
        if ($('#submit_container').css('margin-left') == "300px") {
            $('div').animate({ 'margin-left': '600px' },
                function () {
                    animateContainer(submitValue)
                });
        }
        if ($('#submit_container').css('margin-left') == "600px") {
            $('div').animate(
                { 'margin-left': '0px' },
                function () {
                    animateContainer(submitValue)
                });
        };
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="submit_container">
    <input type="text" id="submit_value">
    <button type="submit" id="submit_trigger">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Plunkr Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/9tj5drY766iQwLvnqC95?p=preview

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#submit_trigger').click(function(){
        var submitValue = $('#submit_value').val();
        console.log(submitValue);
        for(var i = 0; i < submitValue; i++){
            setTimeout(move, i*1000);
        }
      });
    });

    function move(){
        if ($('#submit_container').css('margin-left')=="0px"){
            $('div').animate({'margin-left':'300px'});
        }
        if ($('#submit_container').css('margin-left')=="300px"){
            $('div').animate({'margin-left':'600px'});
        }
        if ($('#submit_container').css('margin-left')=="600px"){
            $('div').animate({'margin-left':'0px'});
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although Nalipu hit the closest answer I was finding for, this solution adds another way of solving it. I appreciate your effort!